# Можно ли использовать экран в Андроид полностью?

Tags: java, android

Задача использовать экран устройства полностью, вместе со строкой где часы и всплывающие сообщения. Можно ли это сделать или по крайней мере заменить черной полосой область которую нельзя использовать для графики?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Добавьте данную строку в метод `onCreate()` вашей Activity

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать это программно:

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Или через `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Если используйте AppCompatActivity можете задать тему так:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2868052/4666979)